# How can I disable the drag event in LibraryBar control

Tags: c#, .net, touch

There are some `LibraryBarItems` in a `LibraryBar` control, when I drag horizontally, all the `LibraryBarItems` move.

But I need to disable this drag event, this means that when I drag the `LibraryBar` horizontally, nothing happens.

p.s. Actually I want to implement the drop event in horizontal direction rather than in Vertical direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a transparent visual item over the top of the control to capture input and only allow it through if want it to get through.